# Creating zip file in windows server from linux server (using jcifs)

Tags: java, linux, windows, jcifs

I need to create a zip file from  Linux machine to Windows Server using JCIFS.I tried creating zip, but getting a corrupted one.The code which I used is pasted below.

```
public boolean createZip(String fileName, String... files) 
{
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, userName, password);
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(fileName, auth);
    try (SmbFileOutputStream zipOutStream = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);) {
        String[] fileArray1 = files;
        for (String file : fileArray1) 
        {
            writeToZipFile(file, zipOutStream, authentication);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("From createZip", e);
    }
    return true;
}

private void writeToZipFile(String file, SmbFileOutputStream zipOutStream,
        final NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication) throws IOException 
{
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    final byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        zipOutStream.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Note: When I tried in a different way by creating a zip file in a temporary folder(Linux machine) and try moving the same using renameTo method of SmbFile. I got authentication failure exception ("Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.").